# pgr_nodeNetwork doesn't use the right data type for osm id in the newly created table

Tags: pgrouting

I was using pgr_nodeNetwork() to generate a new routable network. http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/node_network.html. I found that the old_id (cooresponding to the osm id in the old table) in the new table uses integer as its datatype (see following), the docs says the data type for old_id is bigint though. any ideas to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Your documentation link is very old (pointing to version 2.0). Which version are you using? 
If this is still the case for the current version of pgRouting, we would appreciate, if you could file a bug report: https://github.com/pgrouting/pgrouting/issues

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would be to change the column data type to `bigint`. Changing it from `integer` should be no problem:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN old_id SET DATA TYPE bigint;
```